# fragment doing work in background

Tags: java, android

hey guys i am making a web browser and swipable tabs are involved in it
i want if someone loads webpage and opens new tab the older tab should continue loading and at end it may save itself

problem is if new tabs are created the older ones forget what they were loading and when are selected they start loading the homepage (its in oncreateView of my fragment of one tab)

please help i want to finish it as fast as possible

any help will be appreciated

thankyou guys alot

here is my Fragment

```
package com.android.shubham.muffinbrowserv10;

 //suppose all imports are here
public class Myfragment extends Fragment implements                                       EditText.OnEditorActionListener , ImageButton.OnClickListener
{
    Date pagedate ;
static EditText url;
public static WebView web;
String input =" ";
String Url;
String previousInput = " ";
ProgressBar pro;
ImageButton reload_cancel , refresh , Forward;
static File filesDir;
static ArrayList<String> sb;
Activity myact;

public static Boolean incognitoBool = false , noTabBool = false;

static String homePage = "https://www.google.com";

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();




}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());


    Settings.setZoomButtons(settings.getBoolean(SettingActivity.any_zoom, true));
    Settings.setZoomDrag(settings.getBoolean(SettingActivity.two_finger_zoom , true));
    Settings.setJavachk(settings.getBoolean(SettingActivity.java_script, true));



   noTabBool = settings.getBoolean(SettingActivity.no_tab , false);
    Myfragment.homePage = settings.getString(SettingActivity.home_page , "https://google.com");
    Myfragment.incognitoBool =  settings.getBoolean(SettingActivity.incognito , false);




}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myact = getActivity();


    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bet , container  , false);
    reload_cancel = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    refresh = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    Forward = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.forward);

    refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
    Forward.setOnClickListener(this);
    filesDir = myact.getFilesDir();
    try
    {
        File f = new File(filesDir, "history.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
        OutputStreamWriter opt = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        StringBuilder sbhistory = readHistory();
        pagedate = new Date();
        int date = pagedate.getDate();
        int month = pagedate.getMonth();
        int year = pagedate.getYear();
        String ddate = date+"::"+month+"::"+year;
        if(!sbhistory.toString().contains(ddate))
            opt.write("\n"+"!"+ ddate);
        opt.close();
    }catch (Throwable t){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext() , "Exception in Writing DATE -> " + t , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    url = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.url);
    url.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    pro= (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.pro);
    pro.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    web = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.web);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                         {
                             @Override
                             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                             {
                                 if (url.contains("youtube.com/watch?"))
                                 {
                                     loadpage(url , 3);
                                     return false;
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     loadpage(url, 1);
                                     return true;
                                 }
                             }
                         }
    );

    String intent_url = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("openPageKey");
    if(intent_url == null )
        loadpage(homePage , 1);
    else
        loadpage(intent_url, 1);


    return v;
}
public void setURL(String web_url)
{
    this.url.setText(web_url);

}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    this.url.setText(web.getUrl());
    web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(Settings.getZoomDrag());//opposite by mistake
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(Settings.getZoomButtons());

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(Settings.getJavachk());

    super.onResume();
}






public void loadpage(String url , int val)
{
    switch (val){
        case 1://///////////////////////////////case 1 direct website loading
            Url = url;
            web.loadUrl(Url);
            reload_cancel.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
            break;

        case 2:////////////////////////////////case 2 inbuilt webKit functions
            switch (url)
            {
                case "goBack":
                    web.goBack();
                    break;
                case "goForward":
                    web.goForward();
                    break;
                case "reload":
                    web.reload();
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3://////////////////////////////case 3 using intent to load stuff
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url)));
    }
    new AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            while(pro.getProgress() < 100) publishProgress();

            if (!incognitoBool)
            writeHistory(Url);

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            Myfragment.this.url.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            pro.setProgress(0);
            pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            pro.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Myfragment.this.url.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            Myfragment.this.url.setText(web.getUrl());
            reload_cancel.setImageResource(R.drawable.reload);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
            pro.setProgress(web.getProgress());
        }
    }.execute();
}
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
{

    input = url.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    int order = 1;
    if(!input.equals(previousInput))
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (input.length() >= 4)
        {
            if (input.charAt(input.length() - 3) == '.' || input.charAt(input.length() - 4) == '.')
            {
                flag = true;
                order = 1;
                if (input.contains("www."))
                    input = "https://" + input;
                else
                    input = "https://www." + input;
            }
        }
        if (!flag)
        {

            if (input.contains("youtube.com/watch?"))
            {
                order = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                input = input.replace(" ", "+");
                input = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + input;
                order = 1;
            }
        }

        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) myact.getSystemService(myact.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(url.getWindowToken(), 0);

        previousInput = input;

        loadpage(input, order);
    }
    return false;

}
public void writeHistory(String loadedPage)
{
    try{

        File f = new File(filesDir, "history.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
        OutputStreamWriter opt = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        opt.write("\n"+ loadedPage);
        opt.close();
    }catch (Throwable t){
        Toast.makeText(myact.getBaseContext() , "Exception in Writing History -> " + t , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public static StringBuilder readHistory() throws IOException
{
    File f = new File(filesDir,"history.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    while (true) {

        String line = br.readLine();

        if (line == null) break;

        sb.append("\n" + line);
    }



    return sb;

}
public static ArrayList<String> readHistory(Boolean b) throws IOException
{
    if (b) {

        try {
            File f = new File(filesDir, "history.txt");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            sb = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (true) {

                String line = br.readLine();

                if (line == null) break;
                sb.add(line);

            }


            return sb;

        }catch(IOException e){}
    }//end of if
    return null;
}
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.refresh:
            loadpage("reload" , 2);
            break;
        case R.id.forward:
            if (web.canGoForward())loadpage("goForward" , 2);
            else Toast.makeText(myact.getBaseContext() , "Cant go more forward!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
}
public static void clearcache(){
    web.clearCache(true);
}



}
```

Comment: come on guys dont mark it bad if you are unable to understand please comment it, its my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an AsyncTask ?

when a new tab is opened, the onPause() gets called for that fragment immediately. And put the loading from web code in onStart() instead of onCreateView(). It works the way it is, but onCreateView() is to set up the UI. the loading thing should be on onStart().

Try using an AsyncTask, that should work.

Comment: I got it i Have to use setOffscreenPageLimit() in my ViewPagerAdapter but thankyou Samrat